# Получение массива из значений инпутов и селектов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть страница с несколькими селектами (содержимое берется из бд) и тем же количеством инпутов:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
      <input class="form-control center" value="<?= $value['position'] ?>">
</div>

<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
     <select class="select1 form-control">
         <option value="<?= $value['seo_url'] ?>" selected><?= $value['name'] ?></option>
             <? foreach ($url as $value1) {
                    if ($value['seo_url'] != $value1['seo_url']) {?>
                         <option value="<?= $value1['seo_url'] ?>"><?= $value1['name'] ?></option>
                  <?}
            }?>
     </select>
</div>
```

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку `.save` получить массив вида
`0: {position: "1", name: "гугл", url: "google.com"}
1: {position: "2", name: "яндекс", url: "yandex.ru"}`
                        ....

Пробую писать так, но ничего не получается:

```
$('.save').on('click', function(){

var result = [];
var typeValue = this.id;

    $('#myFormTop input').each(function () {<!--Получаем исходные значения!-->
        var select = $('+ select', this);

        result.push({
        input: $(this).val(),
        select: select.val(),
        url:  select.find('option:selected').text()
     });
    });

  console.log(result);
});
```

Инпуты и селекты:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control center" value="2">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                            <select class="select1 form-control">
                                <option value="" selected="">sd</option>
                                <option value="glavnaya_stranitsa">Главная страница</option>
                                <option value="o_kompanii">О компании</option>                                                                            
                                <option value="usloviya_vozvrata">Условия возврата</option>
                                                ...
                           </select>
                        </div>
```

Кнопка `.save`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="save btn btn-danger" id="top" type="button">Сохранить</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: "ничего не получается" - вообще прямo ничего не происходит?

Comment: `$('+ select', this);` - вот это что значит?

Comment: @Igor, получаю вот это `0
:
{input: "1", select: undefined, selected: ""}
1
:
{input: "2", select: undefined, selected: ""}`

Comment: @Igor, честно говоря код не мой и я мало что в нем понимаю(

Comment: Вы можете каким-то образом поставить селекты в соответствие инпутам? Или они просто по порядку соответствуют друг другу?

Comment: @Igor, инпуты и селекты соответствуют друг другу. Т.е. когда я в цикле их перебираю, получаю из бд данные и вывожу соответственно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.save').on('click', function() {

  var result = [];

  var inputs = $('#myFormTop input');
  var selects = $('#myFormTop select');
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(inputs.length, selects.length); i++) {
    var iValue = $(inputs[i]).val();
    var sValue = $(selects[i]).val();
    var sText = $(selects[i]).find('option:selected').text();
    result.push({
      input: iValue,
      select: sValue,
      url: sText
    });
  }

  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="myFormTop">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
    <input class="form-control center" value="2">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
    <select class="select1 form-control">
      <option value="" selected="">sd</option>
      <option value="glavnaya_stranitsa">Главная страница</option>
      <option value="o_kompanii">О компании</option>                                             <option value="usloviya_vozvrata">Условия возврата</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="save btn btn-danger" id="top" type="button">Сохранить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все работает, только есть одна проблема. Если мы не меняя значения селектов нажмем кнопку `.save` то в массиве, `select: ""` будет пустым. Получается каждый раз надо выбрать значение селекта. Может это связано с html

Comment: @r.mcreal а визуально в них выбраны опции с текстом?

Comment: Визуально да все на месте. Вот что приходит, чтобы было понятнее `{input: "2", select: "", url: "google.com"}`.

Comment: @r.mcreal добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос html (из браузера), содержащий форму с инпутами, селектами и кнопкой `.save`

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, я ничего не пропустил?

Comment: @r.mcreal `<option value="" ...` - ничего не подсказывает?

Comment: Подсказывает, но не могу понять почему так происходит. Ведь я везде получаю `url` одинаково `<select class="select1 form-control">
                                    <option value="<?= $value['seo_url'] ?>" selected><?= $value['name'] ?></option><? foreach ($url as $value1) {
                                        if ($value['seo_url'] != $value1['seo_url']) {?>
                                            <option value="<?= $value1['seo_url'] ?>"><?= $value1['name'] ?></option><? }} ?> </select>`

Comment: @r.mcreal мне ничего не известно про Ваши данные, и я не могу сказать, почему значение `$value['seo_url']` - пустое.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Косяк был в том что название полей в таблицах немного отличались, т.е. собирал я данные из нескольких таблиц и выбранные значения сохранял в другой таблице и потом доставал из-за того что в таблице где я это все сохранял название поле немного отличалось я не мог получить данные. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @r.mcreal На здоровье. Успехов!